# Как сделать так, чтобы messagebox не показывалась только после нажатия ОК

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

Я сделал скрипт, который должен был при нажатии кнопки показывать куча ошибок.

Вот он:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from time import sleep

app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x500")

def showerrors():
    for i in range(1,10):
        sleep(0.5)            
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("еррор", "ошибка")


b = Button(app, text="нажми на меня!", command=showerrors)

b.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

но когда появляется ошибка, следующая ошибка появляется только когда я нажму **`ОК`** на текущей.

Можно ли это убрать? или нельзя?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from time import sleep


app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x500")

def showerrors():
    error = ''
    for i in range(1, 10):
# ???        sleep(0.5)
        error = f"{error}\nошибка: {i}"
    tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Errоr", f"У Вас возникли следующие ОШИБКИ: \n{error}")


b = Button(app, text="Нажми на меня!", command=showerrors)

b.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный `messagebox` создает **модальное** окно, оно поверх всего, пока не закроешь, дальше не движемся. Можно создать **немодальное**, но там уже кнопку ОК надо самому "нарисовать". Вот про немодальные окна https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.0125fa90-63153091-090a69b1-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/56987557/creating-a-modeless-window-using-tkinter